# PDFmake - html table to pdfmake table?

Tags: jquery, html, pdfmake

I am trying to make an application, which contains html tables.

I want a download button, and onClick event, downloads a PDF file containing all the html tables in it.

Can it be done?

Can someone help me with a function that converts the html table into an object so that it can be pushed into a PDF file through pdfmake?

Comment: You can try out http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: You can also try: https://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a working solution over here:
https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/205

```
function ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles) {
var elements = [];
var children = e.childNodes;
if (children.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) p = ParseElement(elements, children[i], p, styles);
}
if (elements.length != 0) {            
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) cnt.push(elements[i]);
}
return p;
}

function ComputeStyle(o, styles) {
for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
    var st = styles[i].trim().toLowerCase().split(":");
    if (st.length == 2) {
        switch (st[0]) {
            case "font-size":{
                o.fontSize = parseInt(st[1]);
                break;
            }
            case "text-align": {
                switch (st[1]) {
                    case "right": o.alignment = 'right'; break;
                    case "center": o.alignment = 'center'; break;
                }
                break;
            }
            case "font-weight": {
                switch (st[1]) {
                    case "bold": o.bold = true; break;
                }
                break;
            }
            case "text-decoration": {
                switch (st[1]) {
                    case "underline": o.decoration = "underline"; break;
                }
                break;
            }
            case "font-style": {
                switch (st[1]) {
                    case "italic": o.italics = true; break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

function ParseElement(cnt, e, p, styles) {
if (!styles) styles = [];
if (e.getAttribute) {
    var nodeStyle = e.getAttribute("style");
    if (nodeStyle) {
        var ns = nodeStyle.split(";");
        for (var k = 0; k < ns.length; k++) styles.push(ns[k]);
    }
}

switch (e.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
    case "#text": {
        var t = { text: e.textContent.replace(/\n/g, "") };
        if (styles) ComputeStyle(t, styles);
        p.text.push(t);
        break;
    }
    case "b":case "strong": {
        //styles.push("font-weight:bold");
        ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles.concat(["font-weight:bold"]));
        break;
    }
    case "u": {
        //styles.push("text-decoration:underline");
        ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles.concat(["text-decoration:underline"]));
        break;
    }
    case "i": {
        //styles.push("font-style:italic");
        ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles.concat(["font-style:italic"]));
        //styles.pop();
        break;
        //cnt.push({ text: e.innerText, bold: false });
    }
    case "span": {
        ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles);
        break;
    }
    case "br": {
        p = CreateParagraph();
        cnt.push(p);
        break;
    }
    case "table":
        {
            var t = {
                table: {
                    widths: [],
                    body: []
                }
            }
            var border = e.getAttribute("border");
            var isBorder = false;
            if (border) if (parseInt(border) == 1) isBorder = true;
            if (!isBorder) t.layout = 'noBorders';
            ParseContainer(t.table.body, e, p, styles);

            var widths = e.getAttribute("widths");
            if (!widths) {
                if (t.table.body.length != 0) {
                    if (t.table.body[0].length != 0) for (var k = 0; k < t.table.body[0].length; k++) t.table.widths.push("*");
                }
            } else {
                var w = widths.split(",");
                for (var k = 0; k < w.length; k++) t.table.widths.push(w[k]);
            }
            cnt.push(t);
            break;
        }
    case "tbody": {
        ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles);
        //p = CreateParagraph();
        break;
    }
    case "tr": {
        var row = [];
        ParseContainer(row, e, p, styles);
        cnt.push(row);
        break;
    }
    case "td": {
        p = CreateParagraph();
        var st = {stack: []}
        st.stack.push(p);

        var rspan = e.getAttribute("rowspan");
        if (rspan) st.rowSpan = parseInt(rspan);
        var cspan = e.getAttribute("colspan");
        if (cspan) st.colSpan = parseInt(cspan);

        ParseContainer(st.stack, e, p, styles);
        cnt.push(st);
        break;
    }
    case "div":case "p": {
        p = CreateParagraph();
        var st = {stack: []}
        st.stack.push(p);
        ComputeStyle(st, styles);
        ParseContainer(st.stack, e, p);

        cnt.push(st);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        console.log("Parsing for node " + e.nodeName + " not found");
        break;
    }
}
return p;
}

function ParseHtml(cnt, htmlText) {
var html = $(htmlText.replace(/\t/g, "").replace(/\n/g, ""));
var p = CreateParagraph();
for (var i = 0; i < html.length; i++) ParseElement(cnt, html.get(i), p);
}

function CreateParagraph() {
var p = {text:[]};
return p;
}

//currently should be wraped in tag div or span
var simpleHtm = "<div>"; 
simpleHtm += "This is <u>simple</u> html parser demo.<br>";  
simpleHtm += "<p style='font-size:20px; text-align:center'>You can set font    
size and align from style</p>";
simpleHtm += "<table border='1'><tr><td>you</td><td>can</td></tr><tr>    <td>use</td><td>tables</td></tr></table>"
simpleHtm += "<table border='1' widths='30%,60%'><tr><td>or</td><td>set</td></tr><tr><td>table</td><td>width from html</td></tr></table><br>"
simpleHtm += "<table border='1' widths='20%,50%'><tr><td>nested</td><td>table</td></tr><tr><td><table border='1'><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table></td><td></td></tr></table>"

simpleHtm += "</div>";
 content = [];
ParseHtml(content, simpleHtm);
pdfMake.createPdf({content: content}).download();
```

You can get the HTML code of any HTML element(I am demonstrating table) using the following code & call the ParseHTML function:

```
var simpleHtm = $('#TableID').prop('outerHTML');
            ParseHtml(tablecontent, simpleHtm);
```

Comment: There was an update and here is a [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/mychn9bo/75/) with the actual working code above.

Comment: This is a good start to what I need to use pdfmake.  Unfortunately this parser doesn't deal with colspan in tables.  Has anyone done that part???

Comment: @mjwrazor I get this error 'Cannot read property '_span' of undefined'

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the PDFMake [getting started](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) page, you have to format your table like this:

```
var docDefinition = {
    content: [{
      table: {
          // headers are automatically repeated if the table spans over multiple pages
          // you can declare how many rows should be treated as headers
          headerRows: 1,
          widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*' ],

          body: [
              [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],
              [ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],
              [ { text: 'Bold value', bold: true }, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4' ]
          ]
      }
    }]
};
```

So you would take your table and get eh widths of each column and then cycle through the rows to create the body array:

```
function createTableDoc() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var wdths;
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        var cell = table.rows[0].cells[i];
        widths[i] = (cell.style.width != ""? cell.style.width : cell.style.offsetWidth); //if the cell's style width is not set, get its' actual width
    }

    var bdy;
    for (var y = 0; y < table.rows.length; y++)
        for (var x = 0; x < table.rows[y].cells.length; x++) {
            body[y][x] = table.rows[y].cells[x].innerHTML;

    var docDef = { content: [{ table: { headerRows: 1, widths: wdths, body: bdy } }] };
    return docDef;
}
```

Comment: Its giving me error that cannot set property '0' of undefined.

Comment: @vbuser2004 check the above accepted solution, it works perfectly fine :)

Comment: @TanujDhaundiyal - my bad! I missed that somehow. Deleted the original comment. Txs.

Answer (score 0):

The full working solution from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mychn9bo/75/). Try yourself running here the example. If you have a main container `div` with a `id="test"`, with this set of functions you just need to call `pdfForElement('test').download();`

```js
function pdfForElement(id) {
  function ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles) {
    var elements = [];
    var children = e.childNodes;
    if (children.length != 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) p = ParseElement(elements, children[i], p, styles);
    }
    if (elements.length != 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) cnt.push(elements[i]);
    }
    return p;
  }

  function ComputeStyle(o, styles) {
    for (var i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
      var st = styles[i].trim().toLowerCase().split(":");
      if (st.length == 2) {
        switch (st[0]) {
          case "font-size":
            {
              o.fontSize = parseInt(st[1]);
              break;
            }
          case "text-align":
            {
              switch (st[1]) {
                case "right":
                  o.alignment = 'right';
                  break;
                case "center":
                  o.alignment = 'center';
                  break;
              }
              break;
            }
          case "font-weight":
            {
              switch (st[1]) {
                case "bold":
                  o.bold = true;
                  break;
              }
              break;
            }
          case "text-decoration":
            {
              switch (st[1]) {
                case "underline":
                  o.decoration = "underline";
                  break;
              }
              break;
            }
          case "font-style":
            {
              switch (st[1]) {
                case "italic":
                  o.italics = true;
                  break;
              }
              break;
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function ParseElement(cnt, e, p, styles) {
    if (!styles) styles = [];
    if (e.getAttribute) {
      var nodeStyle = e.getAttribute("style");
      if (nodeStyle) {
        var ns = nodeStyle.split(";");
        for (var k = 0; k < ns.length; k++) styles.push(ns[k]);
      }
    }

    switch (e.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
      case "#text":
        {
          var t = {
            text: e.textContent.replace(/\n/g, "")
          };
          if (styles) ComputeStyle(t, styles);
          p.text.push(t);
          break;
        }
      case "b":
      case "strong":
        {
          //styles.push("font-weight:bold");
          ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles.concat(["font-weight:bold"]));
          break;
        }
      case "u":
        {
          //styles.push("text-decoration:underline");
          ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles.concat(["text-decoration:underline"]));
          break;
        }
      case "i":
        {
          //styles.push("font-style:italic");
          ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles.concat(["font-style:italic"]));
          //styles.pop();
          break;
          //cnt.push({ text: e.innerText, bold: false });
        }
      case "span":
        {
          ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles);
          break;
        }
      case "br":
        {
          p = CreateParagraph();
          cnt.push(p);
          break;
        }
      case "table":
        {
          var t = {
            table: {
              widths: [],
              body: []
            }
          }
          var border = e.getAttribute("border");
          var isBorder = false;
          if (border)
            if (parseInt(border) == 1) isBorder = true;
          if (!isBorder) t.layout = 'noBorders';
          ParseContainer(t.table.body, e, p, styles);

          var widths = e.getAttribute("widths");
          if (!widths) {
            if (t.table.body.length != 0) {
              if (t.table.body[0].length != 0)
                for (var k = 0; k < t.table.body[0].length; k++) t.table.widths.push("*");
            }
          } else {
            var w = widths.split(",");
            for (var k = 0; k < w.length; k++) t.table.widths.push(w[k]);
          }
          cnt.push(t);
          break;
        }
      case "tbody":
        {
          ParseContainer(cnt, e, p, styles);
          //p = CreateParagraph();
          break;
        }
      case "tr":
        {
          var row = [];
          ParseContainer(row, e, p, styles);
          cnt.push(row);
          break;
        }
      case "td":
        {
          p = CreateParagraph();
          var st = {
            stack: []
          }
          st.stack.push(p);

          var rspan = e.getAttribute("rowspan");
          if (rspan) st.rowSpan = parseInt(rspan);
          var cspan = e.getAttribute("colspan");
          if (cspan) st.colSpan = parseInt(cspan);

          ParseContainer(st.stack, e, p, styles);
          cnt.push(st);
          break;
        }
      case "div":
      case "p":
        {
          p = CreateParagraph();
          var st = {
            stack: []
          }
          st.stack.push(p);
          ComputeStyle(st, styles);
          ParseContainer(st.stack, e, p);

          cnt.push(st);
          break;
        }
      default:
        {
          console.log("Parsing for node " + e.nodeName + " not found");
          break;
        }
    }
    return p;
  }

  function ParseHtml(cnt, htmlText) {
    var html = $(htmlText.replace(/\t/g, "").replace(/\n/g, ""));
    var p = CreateParagraph();
    for (var i = 0; i < html.length; i++) ParseElement(cnt, html.get(i), p);
  }

  function CreateParagraph() {
    var p = {
      text: []
    };
    return p;
  }
  content = [];
  ParseHtml(content, document.getElementById(id).outerHTML);
  return pdfMake.createPdf({
    content: content
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  This is <u>simple</u> html parser demo.
  <br>
  <p style='font-size:20px; text-align:center'>You can set font size and align from style</p>
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
      <td>you</td>
      <td>can</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>use</td>
      <td>tables</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border='1' widths='30%,60%'>
    <tr>
      <td>or</td>
      <td>set</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>table</td>
      <td>width from html</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <table border='1' widths='20%,50%'>
    <tr>
      <td>nested</td>
      <td>table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table border='1'>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Download PDF" onclick="pdfForElement('test').download();">
```

Comment: @Spikolynn it was long time ago, so I don't remember, but I quickly see a difference: you have a full working snippet so that you can test