# How to convert html table to pdf using pdfmake

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, pdfmake

Am trying to convert my html table to pdf using pdfmake http://pdfmake.org/ but i cant make it to how to use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php $pdffile = md5(time()).'.pdf'; ?>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/ecmascript"></script>
<script src="pdfmake.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vfs_fonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
           var table = document.getElementById('table').outerHTML;
           var table = document.getElementById('table').innerHTML; // Same response with outerHTML
           var table = document.getElementById('table').value; // nothing is happening here
       docDefinition = {
            content: table   
       }
       pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('<?php print $pdffile; ?>');
    });
</script>
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db');
    if($con){
        echo 'connected'.'<br/>';

        $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $query_db = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_db) > 0){
?>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query_db)): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php print $data['user_id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php print $data['username']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php print $data['email']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </tbody>        
        </table>
<?php           

        }else echo 'not data';
    }else echo 'error';
?>
</html>
```

From the code i have posted am getting html code not html table on my pdf file any way out sorry am not good at javascript?

Comment: we need way more info than that. Can you please try to re-explain what output you're seeing and expecting? At the moment, it doesnt make much sense.

Comment: devdonkey when the pdf is created am getting code not table

Comment: I think this was already answered here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 4):

1.You cannot put HTML table in content of document definition object when using PDFMAKE
2.What you need to do is generate an array of arrays.
The main array is body array in table object in document definition object.So now extract each row of your html table wise and push each cell (row-wise) into an array..after the row is finished and all cell data of particular row is pushed into the body array.This needs to be done for all rows.That's it!
A simple example is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title> 
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction()
    {


        var docDefinition = {
  content: [
{
  table: {


    body: [
      [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],
      [ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],
      [ { text: 'Bold value', bold: true }, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4' ]
    ]
  }
}]}
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('Report.pdf');

    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct syntax to pass the table data :-

```
var docDefinition = {
  content: [
{
  table: {


    body: [
      [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],
      [ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],
      [ { text: 'Bold value', bold: true }, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4' ]
    ]
  }
}
```

]
};

This will print the HTML table and not the html code on the pdf file.You need to pass the table data in this format.

Comment: Bhawana, hey you mean after looping my table for user view i should also loop it for pdf download?

Comment: Yes you need to create a javascript function to put the table data in the required format.

Comment: You can refer to an earlier post for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610129/pdfmake-html-table-to-pdfmake-table

Comment: I believe we  are dealing with wrong plugin, that in the world of programming i trust should not be practiced, i found a different solution http://kayalshri.github.io/tableExport.jquery.plugin/ and working only i need to play around to adjust some settings