# how to save pdf using pdfMake in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, pdfmake

I want to create pdf file and save it into the folder. I have created code for create pdf but its not working for save pdf into folder.

My code is :

```
  $scope.export = function(){
        $scope.hidebutton = false;
            var date = new Date();
            $scope.FromDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'ddHHMMmmyyyyss');        
            html2canvas(document.getElementById('printPlanId'), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                    var docDefinition = {
                        content: [{
                            pageSize: 'A4',
                            image: data,
                            width: 500,     
                        }]
                    };
                    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download($scope.FromDate+"-"+"report.pdf");                                

                }
            });
```

I want to save pdf into folder.

Comment: this is you need? jsPdf https://stackoverflow.com/a/23684363/4921471

Comment: can i do same using pdfMake ?

Comment: yes, would be as i read in its doc. But download method got not params, download()

Comment: how can i do this ?

Comment: pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();

Comment: mm, ive been reading dos, and searching any example of download, and nothig

Comment: sorry, download could taken name of file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863144/how-to-convert-html-table-to-pdf-using-pdfmake

Comment: i did this its only download the pdf.  I want to know  how can i save directly it into the folder after generating PDF ?

Comment: mm, always need approve from user to download

Comment: The folder in which a document is downloaded depends on the user's browser settings.